# Why does Boolean([]) return true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript `[] == 0` returns true, as expected. But `Boolean([])` also returns true.

I would expect it to return false, as `== 0` checks for false.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean). It explains both of your provided examples.

Comment: You can check [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. Also, `==` isn't the same as `===`

Comment: `[] == 0` because `Number([]) == 0` because `Number(String([])) == 0` because `Number("") == 0`. Try this: `a = []; console.log(a == 0); a.toString = () => "[]"; console.log(a == 0);`

Answer (score 2):

It is simply just how the `Boolean()` function is implemented.

If you look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) for the `Boolean()` function you will find this (emphasis mine)

> The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a boolean value, if necessary. If the value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false. **All other values, including any object, an empty array ([]), or the string "false", create an object with an initial value of true.**